# How do I make the initial page load smaller?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying for longer than I care to admit to get our site to load with a smaller display - I've tried a couple dozen different workarounds with JS, CSS, & HTML all involved.  I believe it has to do with the viewport meta tag but nothing I do elicits a response from this. Below is the HTML head section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Autumn Lane</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icon-64.png">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </head>
```

Again, the issue is that the site loads with too large a scale on a full-size device (laptop) - any ideas?

Comment: Is there a URL we can look at?

Comment: yes, of course: www.autumnlanepaperie.com

Comment: OK, looks pretty normal. What exactly do you mean by "too large a scale on a full-size device (laptop)"?

Comment: Hmmm .. I sure hope this isn't a case of my personal settings.  Basically, though, when the site loads, I have to zoom out to see the social media button footer & the site is blown out.  My wife has had similar results & we're holding off announcing the site until we're satisfied we've done all we can to get it all scaled like we want.,

Comment: At least for me, on Chrome, it looks normal. The width is 100% with no horizontal scroll. Whether the social media icons are off the screen or not depends on how wide I make the window.

Comment: Ok, I think we're both on Firefox.  Is there a way to set the window size upon initial load?  Personally, I'd rather have the page set to the height rather than the width but I wasn't able to make that work.

Comment: Looks exactly the same on Firefox. AFAIK there's not way to set browser zoom (it's considered a user-settable value). If you make the width of the carousel smaller for a given screen width then it makes the carousel height smaller and achieves the effect, i.e. shrinking the overall screen.

Comment: Ok, good to know that I wasn't just absolute rubbish at finding the answer, then!  Thanks amigo